# Is it possible to pass inputted values from my website to any other website on the internet

Tags: javascript, html, post, local-storage

Is it possible to pass inputted values from my website to any other website on the internet. I have saved the input to localstorage. Now I want to pass it on to another website which requires a username. The other website has the input ID="userusername". Is it possible without the website expecting the value being posted with for example POST or GET method?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function passvalues(){
        var pass=document.getElementByID("name").value;
        localStorage.setItem("textvalue", pass);
        return false;
    }

</script>

<form method="POST" action="whatever website">
    <input type="name" placeholder="Name" id="name"/>
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Login" onclick="passvalues();"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to understand what to expect.

Comment: _"Is it possible to pass [...] to any other website on the internet"_. No, not to any website. It might be possible on some old/poorly made site, but most websites nowadays protect against XSRF by requiring a unique token in the login form, so that you need to load their login page to get that token before being able to submit the form to it ([Stack Overflow does it](https://imgur.com/a/Y3AdFAa), for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalStorage is limited to protocol of the specified page so you can pass your locally stored data to another website using post method. But this will not be the case if your protocol of the page changes.